# too_many_buckets_exception in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am facing an issue in ElasticSearch aggregation. We are using RestHighLevelClient for querying ElasticSearch in Java.

Exception is -

> ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception
>   [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=]]; nested:
>   ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception
>   [type=too_many_buckets_exception, reason=Trying to create too many
>   buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [20000] but was [20001]. This
>   limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level
>   setting.]];

I have changed search.max_buckets using a PUT request but still, I am facing this issue.

> PUT /_cluster/settings {   "persistent" : { 
>       "search.max_buckets":20000   }    }

As per our requirement first, we have to aggregate data on daily bases then hourly basis then ruleId basis. Aggregation would look like below level -

```
Day{
    1:00[
       {
       ruleId : 1 ,
       count : 20
       },
       {
       ruleId : 2 ,
       count : 25
       }
    ],
    2:00[
    {
       ruleId : 1 ,
       count : 20
       },
       {
       ruleId : 2 ,
       count : 25
       }
    ]
```

Now my code is -

```
    final List<DTO> violationCaseMgmtDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            RangeQueryBuilder queryBuilders =
                (end_timestmp > 0 ? customTimeRangeQueryBuilder(start_timestmp, end_timestmp, generationTime)
                    : daysTimeRangeQueryBuilder(14, generationTime));

            BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
            boolQuery.must(queryBuilders);
            boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("pvGroupBy", true));
            boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("pvInformation", false));
            TopHitsAggregationBuilder topHitsAggregationBuilder =
                AggregationBuilders.topHits("topHits").docValueField(policyId).sort(generationTime, SortOrder.DESC);

            TermsAggregationBuilder termsAggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms("distinct").field(policyId).size(10000)
                .subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder);

            DateHistogramAggregationBuilder timeHistogramAggregationBuilder =
                AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("by_hour").field("eventDateTime")
                    .fixedInterval(DateHistogramInterval.HOUR).subAggregation(termsAggregation);

            DateHistogramAggregationBuilder dateHistogramAggregationBuilder =
                AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("by_day").field("eventDateTime")
                    .fixedInterval(DateHistogramInterval.DAY).subAggregation(timeHistogramAggregationBuilder);

            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(violationDataModel);
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(dateHistogramAggregationBuilder);
            searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQuery);
            searchSourceBuilder.from(offset);
            searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);
            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            SearchResponse searchResponse = null;

            searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

            ParsedDateHistogram parsedDateHistogram = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("by_day");

            parsedDateHistogram.getBuckets().parallelStream().forEach(dayBucket -> {


                ParsedDateHistogram hourBasedData = dayBucket.getAggregations().get("by_hour");

                hourBasedData.getBuckets().parallelStream().forEach(hourBucket -> {

                    // TimeLine timeLine = new TimeLine();
                    String dateTime = hourBucket.getKeyAsString();
                    // long dateInLong = DateUtil.getMiliSecondFromStringDate(dateTime);
                    // timeLine.setViolationEventTime(dateTime);

                    ParsedLongTerms distinctPolicys = hourBucket.getAggregations().get("distinct");
                    distinctPolicys.getBuckets().parallelStream().forEach(policyBucket -> {

                        DTO violationCaseManagementDTO = new DTO();
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setDataAggregated(true);
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setEventDateTime(dateTime);
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setRuleId(Long.valueOf(policyBucket.getKey().toString()));

                        ParsedTopHits parsedTopHits = policyBucket.getAggregations().get("topHits");
                        SearchHit[] searchHits = parsedTopHits.getHits().getHits();
                        SearchHit searchHit = searchHits[0];

                        String source = searchHit.getSourceAsString();
                        ViolationDataModel violationModel = null;
                        try {
                            violationModel = objectMapper.readValue(source, ViolationDataModel.class);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setRuleName(violationModel.getRuleName());
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setGenerationTime(violationModel.getGenerationTime());
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setPriority(violationModel.getPriority());
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setStatus(violationModel.getViolationStatus());
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setViolationId(violationModel.getId());
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setEntity(violationModel.getViolator());
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setViolationType(violationModel.getViolationEntityType());
                        violationCaseManagementDTO.setIndicatorsOfAttack( (int)
                            (policyBucket.getDocCount() * violationModel.getNoOfViolatedEvents()));
                        violationCaseMgmtDtos.add(violationCaseManagementDTO);

                    });
                  //  violationCaseMgmtDtos.sort((d1,d2) -> d1.getEventDateTime().compareTo(d2.getEventDateTime()));
                });

            });

            List<DTO> realtimeViolation = findViolationWithoutGrouping(start_timestmp,  end_timestmp,  offset,  size);
            realtimeViolation.stream().forEach(action -> violationCaseMgmtDtos.add(action)); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Objects.nonNull(violationCaseMgmtDtos) && violationCaseMgmtDtos.size() > 0) {
            return violationCaseMgmtDtos.stream()
                .filter(violationDto -> Objects.nonNull(violationDto))
                .sorted((d1,d2) -> d2.getEventDateTime().compareTo(d1.getEventDateTime()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return violationCaseMgmtDtos;
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you had 20001 buckets you need to augment `search.max_buckets` higher than 20000.

Comment: @Val Thanks for the comment. Earlier it gives me error for 10000 bucket then i have increased it to 20000 then it gives me error for 20000 then i have increased it 50000 then it gives me error for 50000.

Comment: I suggest you look into the [`composite` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) instead of trying to retrieve all term buckets at once.

Comment: I agreed with Val about composite aggregation usage. The next wizard https://plnkr.co/edit/iJSFP8eRrhC7l7Hx2XOL?p=preview&preview might help you what type of aggregation suites best according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are using ES version 7.x.x then you can add `terminate_after` clause to your query to limit the number of buckets into which the data would be divided into. This happens mostly when the data your are trying to aggregate has a high degree of randomness.

If your data contains text then it would better to aggregate on `.keyword` field (assuming you are using default settings).

```
POST your_index/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "your_target_field": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "terminate_after": 10000,
  "version": true,
  "aggs": {
    "title": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "your_target_field.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
}
```